# Json overwriting itself in Python

Tags: python, json, file-io

I am giving a try in backend and I am failing in parsing Twitters stream API. I want to create Json file with timestamp, name, tweet and screen name. That seems to be working. But when I try to write it in file - entry overwrites already existing one. It does not continues. I red here that for some `outfile.write('\n')` worked. Tried and still new entry overwrites previous one

```
    with open('text2', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump({'time': time.time(), 'screenName': screenName, 'text': text, 'name': name}, outfile, indent = 4, sort_keys=True)
        outfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you append to file in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-file-in-python)

Comment: no, it's not. You can't append content to a json file like it would be a txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the file use `a` (append) instead of `w` (write).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Well, the resulting content in `test2` is no valid JSON anymore. That should be kept in mind.

Comment: @Boldewyn and how to add consatntly new Json objects and still get valid Json?

Comment: Build the object in memory (e.g. as a list or dict) containing all the entries and serialize it all at once.